# List of special PHP characters

Tags: php, string

I mean escaped characters used in double quoted strings. Are there any other besides:

```
\r
\t
\n
```

?

Comment: Yes! A list can be found [at the PHP documentation for double-quoted strings](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: because the OP was to lazy to check the manual

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak I didn't actually downvote it but I'd assume it's because the answer can be very clearly found in the official documentation as many others have already pointed out

Comment: I just want to know. Thanks though.:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! A list can be found [at the PHP documentation for double-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

> - `\n`: linefeed (LF or 0x0A (10) in ASCII)
> - `\r`: carriage return (CR or 0x0D (13) in ASCII)
> - `\t` horizontal tab (HT or 0x09 (9) in ASCII)
> - `\v` vertical tab (VT or 0x0B (11) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.2.5)
> - `\e` escape (ESC or 0x1B (27) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.4.0)
> - `\f` form feed (FF or 0x0C (12) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.2.5)
> - `\\` backslash
> - `\$` dollar sign
> - `\"` double-quote
> - `\[0-7]{1,3}` the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation
> - `\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}` the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in hexadecimal notation

Comment: tks! do u know if there's any function in php that interpretes these characters? I want to pass `'\n'` (in single quotes) and the function should return the new line character

Comment: nl2br() the manual, the manual!

Comment: @Dagon: It’s a literal backslash followed by an `n`, and `<br>` isn’t the newline character…

Comment: @AnnaK.: I think you’d probably have to just do the replacements manually. For example, `str_replace(['\n', '\r', …], ["\n", "\r", …], $someString)`.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this in the Q. Basically I want `str_replace("\n", '\n', $str);` But I was wondering if there's some magic function that does this automatically so I don't have to run 10 str_replaces :)

Comment: @AnnaK.: Well, as in that snippet, you can use arrays to perform multiple replacements more concisely, but I don’t know of a magic function. (Depending on your situation, you *might* be able to re-quote the string and use `json_decode`, but… don’t do that unless you’re decoding JSON, probably. `:)`)

Comment: it works with eval('return "\n";') !

Comment: @AnnaK.: Sure. But where are you getting the string?

Comment: @AnnaK.: Use `str_replace`. Never `eval` user input, ever.

Comment: y i know all the horror stories about eval. anyway i was just playing with smth silly, it doesnt matter anymore..

Answer (score 4):

```
 ?\a ⇒ 7                 ; control-g, C-g
 ?\b ⇒ 8                 ; backspace, <BS>, C-h
 ?\t ⇒ 9                 ; tab, <TAB>, C-i
 ?\n ⇒ 10                ; newline, C-j
 ?\v ⇒ 11                ; vertical tab, C-k
 ?\f ⇒ 12                ; formfeed character, C-l
 ?\r ⇒ 13                ; carriage return, <RET>, C-m
 ?\e ⇒ 27                ; escape character, <ESC>, C-[
 ?\s ⇒ 32                ; space character, <SPC>
 ?\\ ⇒ 92                ; backslash character, \
 ?\d ⇒ 127               ; delete character, <DEL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the documentation about [Double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)?

```
Sequence        Meaning
\n              linefeed (LF or 0x0A (10) in ASCII)
\r              carriage return (CR or 0x0D (13) in ASCII)
\t              horizontal tab (HT or 0x09 (9) in ASCII)
\v              vertical tab (VT or 0x0B (11) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.2.5)
\e              escape (ESC or 0x1B (27) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.4.0)
\f              form feed (FF or 0x0C (12) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.2.5)
\\              backslash
\$              dollar sign
\"              double-quote
\[0-7]{1,3}     the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation
\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}  the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in hexadecimal notation
```