# Escape HTML file as string for use as regex string

Tags: php, regex

I'm loading HTML file to a variable and use it in preg_match as a matched string.

Now what I need is to escape all special characters existing to make it work with regex.

```
TAB => \t
NEWLINE => \n
CARRIEG RETURN => \r
CARRIEG RETURN+NEWLINE => \n
VERTICAL TAB => \cK
and other special characters...
```

For example, this HTML file

```
text \text text <tag attr="val"> text </tag> 
text text $ ^ text
{} text text text 
text | text
```

Will convert to this

```
text \\text text \<tag attr\=\"val\"\> text \<\/tag\> \ntext text \$ \^ text\n\{\} text text text \ntext \| text
```

There are built-in functions that will make my life easier?

**UPDATE:**

I use this function to make string accessible for regex functions which seem works correctly:

```
private function real_regular_expression_string($text) {
    // Escape backslashes
    $text = preg_replace('/[\\\\]/', '\\\\', $text);
    // Escape regular expression special character
    $text = preg_quote($text, '/');
    // Search and Replace variable for another special characters
    $search = [
        "\n",   // 2 - New line character
        "\r",   // 3 - Carriage-Return character
        "\t",   // 4 - Horizontal tab character
        "\v",   // 5 - Vertical tab character
        "\e",   // 6 - Escape character
        "\f",   // 7 - Form-feed character
    ];
    $replace = [
        '\n',   // 2 
        '\r',   // 3
        '\t',   // 4
        '\cK',  // 5
        '\a',   // 6
        '\f',   // 7
    ];
    $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
    // A littel fix
    $text = str_replace('\r\n', '\n', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Any idea how to make it better?

However, now preg_match not work correctly :\

I have this regex string from the function above:

```
/(?:(?:.*)(?:\r\n|\r|\n))*(?<offset>.*)(?:\$\{ALMdOG \= \n\t\$\{ALMdOG\} \n\})/
```

and the HTML file is:

```
text text text text 
numerofcharacters ${ALMdOG = 
    ${ALMdOG} 
} 
text text text text 
text text text text 
text text text text
```

which should work and stop my suffering, any idea :\?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-quote.php).

From the docs:

> `preg_quote()` takes `str` and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax.

Comment: I read about this function, it doesn't work for a new-line or tab character and maybe more others that I didn't consider.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in function for that. You'll have to replace those by yourself using `str_replace` (or `preg_replace`). For a list of special characters you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16431310/8528014). Note that you should do this _before_ calling `preg_quote`, since the newly introduced backslashes also need to be escaped.

Comment: For example: [`str_replace("\n", "\\n", $str)`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6ec55485aded3e18ef83f90f490e44be0618d82) for newline characters.

Comment: That's what I have done so far. the problem starts when I using preg_quote which escaped the back-slash and change it to \\n; in that case of regex, is not a new line but escaped back-slash and n character.

Comment: In more complex code, I know how to do it right. I just wonder if there is a simple way for this before I start to make things messy

Comment: No, I don't think that there is any way to do this simpler; this is a rather special use case, which is unlikely to be covered by standard libraries.